# Histogram gives inaccurate results in matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram

I am trying tp create a histogram in Matlab with my data( 1x150 ) but it comes up wrong. Firstly I should have 12 ticks and each ticks has a value but matlab obly gives me 6 ticks. the other 6 ticks are missing I could not figure out why.

my data;

```
  myData.income=         

175000
65000
35000
55000
5000
65000
25000
45000 
55000
95000
45000
45000
...
5000   
15000
```

Here is my code;

```
STATS.histograms=figure(8);
histogram(myData.income)
xlabel('Annual income') % x-axis label
ylabel('# of participants') % y-axis label
xticks([ 0 20000 40000 60000 80000 100000 120000 140000 160000 180000 200000 220000])
xticklabels({'5.000 < ','15.000','25.000','35.000','45.000', ... 
'55.000','65.000','75.000','85.000','95.000','125.000','150.000 >'})
xlim([0 230000]); %limits
ylim([0 45]);
title('Income ');
savefig('income');
```

Also I checked my data, there are no missing values. When I run this code matlab only gives me a histogram with between 15.000 - 85.000 ticks.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show a [mcve] (real data)

Comment: I found my problem!

Comment: Either answer it, or delete the question then

Comment: @australopithecus This is great for you. But maybe someone else facing the same problem could benefit from this?

Comment: @glglgl I am answering it now

Comment: @AnderBiguri yes I am answering it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. When I use `hiscounts` it gives me only 6 values. Since my incomes are recoreded as 5000, 15000, 25000 etc... this function adds every '5000' value to the 5000 column.

To be more clear; It considers 25000 as 5000. When I run the 'histcounts' function it was giving me this output;

```
>> histcounts(myData.income)

ans =

    26    44    16     6     6     3
```

This was the issue of my inaccurate histogrtam data. So I recode my every income value with these lines;

```
%hist transform
bir = myData.income(:,1) == 5000 ;
iki = myData.income(:,1) == 15000 ;
uc = myData.income(:,1)== 25000;
dort = myData.income(:,1)== 35000;
bes = myData.income(:,1) == 45000;
alti = myData.income(:,1)==55000;
yedi = myData.income(:,1)==65000;
sekiz = myData.income(:,1)==75000;
dokuz = myData.income(:,1)==85000;
on = myData.income(:,1)==95000;
onbir = myData.income(:,1)==125000;
oniki = myData.income(:,1)==175000;
% recoding
 myData.income(bir) = 1 ;
 myData.income(iki) = 2 ;
 myData.income(uc) = 3 ;
 myData.income(dort) = 4 ;
 myData.income(bes) = 5 ;
 myData.income(alti) = 6 ;
 myData.income(yedi) = 7 ;
 myData.income(sekiz) = 8 ;
 myData.income(dokuz) = 9 ;
 myData.income(on) = 10 ;
 myData.income(onbir) = 11 ;
 myData.income(oniki) = 12 ;
```

Thanks to these lines there are no longer overwriting or binding into the same values.

Bu be careful, since we changed our values (from 5000 to 1) we need to arranage our `xticks`. so in my example the new ticks should be `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12]` and our `xlimit` will be from 0 to 13 or 1 to 12. It is up to you! I personally like space between y-axis and my data bars. Here is the final code;

```
STATS.histograms=figure(8);
histogram(myData.income)
xlabel('Annual income') % x-axis label
ylabel('# of participants') % y-axis label
xticks([ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12])
xticklabels({'5.000 < ','15.000','25.000','35.000','45.000', ... 
'55.000','65.000','75.000','85.000','95.000','125.000','150.000 >'})
xlim([0 13]); %limits
ylim([0 45]);
title('Income ');
savefig('income');
```

**EDIT**

You may want to save your recoded variables into a different variable rather than your original one.

Comment: This seems like a fudge, but because it's unclear what's even going on (mainly because we have no idea what your data looks like, as you haven't shown a sample / explained it) there is no easy way to tell you how to simplify what you're doing.

Comment: @Wolfie I did answer my question, My data is 150x1 matrix and has {5.000 , 15.000 , ... 175.000] as inputs.

Comment: @Wolfie yes it works, but I cannot accept it as answer since there is a time restriction(2 days)